# EF Core query to Oracle with non unicode column throwing "ORA-12704: character set mismatch"

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, unicode, entity-framework-core

I have this code in DataContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    #region Province

    var provinceEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Province>();
    provinceEntity.ToTable("GTPROVINCES");

    #region properties

    provinceEntity.Property(table => table.ProvinceId).HasColumnName("PROVINCEID");
    provinceEntity.Property(table => table.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").IsUnicode(false);

    #endregion properties

    #region keys

    provinceEntity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProvinceId });
    #endregion keys

    #endregion Province
}
```

And I have an `ApiController` with this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    string test1 = "test1";
    string test2 = "test2";

    var lista = unitOfWork.ProvinceRepository.Fetch().Select(x => new
        {
            name = x.Name == test1 ? test1 : test2
        });
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lista.ToQueryString());
    lista.ToList();

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

When `ToList()` is run, I get this error:

> ORA-12704: character set mismatch

The problem is that the query launched to database is

```
DECLARE 
l_sql     varchar2(32767);
l_cur     pls_integer;
l_execute pls_integer;

BEGIN
l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_sql := 'SELECT CASE
    WHEN "g"."NAME" = :test1_0 THEN :test1_0
    ELSE :test2_1
END "name"
FROM "GTPROVINCES" "g"';
dbms_sql.parse(l_cur, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':test1_0', 'test1');
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':test2_1', N'test2');
l_execute:= dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
dbms_sql.return_result(l_cur);
END;
```

And it is mixing test1 in ansi characters and test2 in unicode characters.

Could anyone help me, please?

I expected all literals was in ansi characters.

Comment: What does `ansi characters` even mean? Even the US doesn't use the 7-bit US-ASCII character set. That can't even handle all English words, like naïve. Whatever collation/character set that column uses, it's not ANSI (assuming you mean the 7-bit ASCII)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In Windows, Microsoft uses "ANSI" as shorthand for "local codepage" - I assume Oracle does something similar.

Comment: @Dai that's a multi-level misconception used by people that didn't really have to work with codepages beyond Latin1 a) Windows is Unicode and b) the "system" locale is just the default codepage for non-Unicode programs, of which there should be none left. Oracle is worse than just setting the local wrong, depending on the driver. The ORACLE_HOME can override other locale settings, both the client *and* the server settings.

Comment: Windows is a Unicode OS. .NET strings are Unicode, the same way Java, Python 3 and JavaScript strings are Unicode. To get `character set mismatch` the Oracle driver (which one?) must have tried to translate the Unicode text to the wrong codepage. This happened a lot with older Oracle-built drivers that simply ignored any other setting than Oracle Home's. What's the actual collation/codepage of that column? Which driver is used? What's the connection string?

Comment: When I say ansi I mean not unicode.
Column type is VARCHAR2(35).  How could I get collation?
The driver I use is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess which I think is the default driver.
The connection string is
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=TEST)));User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword;

Comment: NLS_SORT = SPANISH
NLS_COMP = BINARY

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to remove the ternary operation:

```
 name = x.Name == test1 ? test1 : test2)
```

... and instead return a flag for whether the name matches your criteria before finally returning your desired value. EF will respect the Unicode vs. non-unicode string comparison for properties, however when you introduce effectively an `if`/`else` into the clause the "test2" unicode string will get parsed as a Unicode string into the query expression which will then try to return either the non-Unicode value or the Unicode one which leads to the error.

For instance this should work:

```
var lista = unitOfWork.ProvinceRepository.Fetch().Select(x => new
    {
        isTest1 = x.Name == test1
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        name = isTest1 ? test1 : test2
    }).ToList();
```

... as an example. This forms a double-projection where the first `Select` is translated to SQL while the second, after the `AsEnumerable`, is executed in memory. If you have `Where` clauses, be sure to add them before the `AsEnumerable`. Also the first `Select` would need to contain any values from the table rows you will want to include in the final projection. This method can be useful for situations where you want values that aren't translatable into SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this solution doesn't help me. We have a very large application in which we have detected performance problems and they were due to the fact that the definition of the fields in EF were not marked as non-unicode and when launching the query it caused a conversion in the database and that it did not use the values ​​correctly. indices.
We have added a SetIsUnicode(false) to all the fields, but we cannot go query by query modifying it. We only need that in EF literals never use unicode

Comment: Yes, technical debt from developing a large system without considerations to how/where  Unicode (.Net) to VARCHAR vs NVARCHAR may cause conflicts might be expensive to go through and repair.  One thing that might help: https://benjaminray.com/codebase/force-strings-to-use-varchar-in-entity-framework-core/ though this assumes all strings would be stored as VARCHAR and may or may not work in this scenario. There are a few discussions in the EF Core group around handling and inferring encoding from property definitions but there appear to be several complex cases that still cause issues.

Comment: That's the solution I'm currently using to mark all the fields as unicode, the problem is that the literals are passed as non-unicode and that's why I get the error.
What I need is for those literals to be passed in non-unicode as well

Comment: It's a sucky problem. You could try raising it with the EF Core team on Github but I wouldn't expect any action on it any time soon, though they might know of some work-around. Essentially a transformation like that cannot be done at the SQL level without consequences as you've seen so the solution is to find these problems and fix them properly. This can either be done with double-projection or if you are projecting to something like a DTO/ViewModel, change them so those classes can do the substitution based on state/flag coming from the database. AFAIK there is no quick fix.